Intergrating $ \int_{M} f (x.,y,z,w)\ d {\rm Vol}_3 $
I want to integrate $$ I = \int_{M} f (x.,y,z,w)\ d {\rm
Vol}_3 $$where $f(x,y,z,w) = (x+y)e^{z+w} $, and
$M = \{x+y+z+w = 1, x,y,z,w > 0\} $.
I need to find a parameterization of M; if I consider $ U = \{x+y+z < 1, x,y,z > 0\} $ and define $$r(x,y,z) = (x,y,z,1-x-y-z), r : R^3 \to M $$
Using the change of variable theorem, then $$I = \int_{U} f (r(x,y,z)) \sqrt(\Gamma({\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}})) $$ Where $\Gamma$ is Gram Matrix.
However, after plugging the values of $\sqrt(\Gamma) $, I did not succeed in integrating. I'd appreciate any help.

Let’s see the rest of the work. The set-up of the iterated integral is what is of interest.
